# Play Store Not Supported Deveices Releasing App

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

I'm trying to release my app on the play store. But I notice that asking for this permission

> uses-feature android:name="FEATURE_NFC_HOST_CARD_EMULATION"

I've neither one supported device. 
How can I solve?

Comment: I have newer seen such a feature `FEATURE_NFC_HOST_CARD_EMULATION`. I'm afraid that no devices support it. Why do you need it? Do you really need it?

Comment: Did you really need this feature ?

Comment: Yes I do, I need to emulate a nfc card and this feature is required.